# autofilter not working properly

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to filter out some cells based on values in a column, but I'm fearing that the first filter action pollutes the rest, although I try to unset the filter by setting filtermode to false.

My select method looks like this:

```
Function GetRowRange(sheetRange, column, value) As Range
'check for a valid section column
sheetRange.AutoFilterMode = False
sheetRange.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=column, Criteria1:=value
Set GetRowRange = sheetRange.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
MsgBox ("col:" & column & " val: " & value & " rows:" & GetRowRange.Rows.Count)
sheetRange.AutoFilterMode = False
End Function
```

And from the msgbox I can see that only the first returns any rows

Comment: Somehow, this code looks familiar! ;-)

Comment: @PeterAlbert I thought I'd create a new thread and not take advantage of your kind help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite a nasty problem! :-)

The problem is that after applying the Autofilter and `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`, your new Range object is consisting of multiple, combined ranges.

E.g. when filtering this table for `B`,
[image]

your range object will have 3 areas, each 1x2 cells. For some strange reason, `Rows.Count`does not take those areas into account, so `Selection.Rows.Count`is 1 though it should be 3. However, if you loop over the Rows enumeration, it'll work as expected:

```
lngCount = 0
For Each r In Selection.Rows
    lngCount = lngCount + 1
Next
```

This will return 3.

So your `GetRowRange` will return the right range, but the `.Rows.Count` routine will deliver the wrong result. Use this function instead:

```
Function RowCount(rngAreas As Range) As Long
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In rngAreas.Areas
        lngCount = lngCount + rng.Rows.Count
    Next
    RowCount = lngCount
End Function
```

Just a side note: be aware that your `GetRowRange` will also always return the first header row of your table, so handle this accordingly!

Comment: As a side note, do you know if excel functions like .CountiF are affected by this - I have this weird bug, that when I do this on one column, Field:=2 it works fine, but when Field:=3 it doesn't work, and I only get like 2 or 3 rows returned if I run .CountIf on the column

Comment: don't know. :-( maybe try `.Subtotal`instead?